# Can We Replace value of vector element using Iterator?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

How Iterators actually work in vectors.If we need to replace a data element in vector, can we proceed through iterator or do we need some other kind of implementation to do so?

Following is my code for above Query

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector <string> v;
vector <string> :: iterator it;
int main()
{
    int t,l,i;
    cin >> t;
    for(i=0;i<t;i++){
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        v.push_back(s);
    }
    string s2="replaceable String";
    //Now I want to change some string at index i in vector v to string s2
    for(it=v.begin();it!=v.end();it++){
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't have a clear error with some code causing that error then don't post on this site

Comment: in other words, try it out first. If you get an error, try and look for other people who had that error. IF you still can't figure it out after your own research, then post your question, code, and what you have tried so we can help you troubleshoot your error.

Comment: Yes, you can modify elements via iterators.

Comment: Assuming `it` is valid iterator, you can alter the value pointing to it like this: `*it = 123`.

Comment: I have posted my code along with the question now.

Answer (score -1):

Iterators are used to point to *slots* or locations in vectors.

The iterators of a `std::vector` follow the concept of [Random Interators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator).

You can assign an iterator to the beginning of a vector.

You can assign an iterator to the result of `std::find`.

You can increment an iterator.

You can access the element in an array by dereferencing the interator.

What else do you need?

Comment: I want to replace the value contained at a particular index of my container.Can we do this via iterator?